# Set request_uri header in auth_request url location

Tags: nginx, http-headers, nginx-location

I want to use `$request_uri` of specific location in another location. here is my nginx config:

```
location ~* ^/admin-panel/rest/(.*) {
    set    $url $request_uri;
    auth_request        /admin/admin_authentication/check_access;

    proxy_pass        http://nginx:8000/$1$is_args$args;
}

location /admin/admin_authentication/check_access {
    uwsgi_param   HTTP_X_URL $url; # $url is empty here :(
    include           uwsgi_params;

    set $micros_addr micros:80;
    uwsgi_pass        $micros_addr;
}
```

I think I do something wrong. in `/admin/admin_authentication/check_access` location `$url` is empty. I want to access `$request_uri` of  `^/admin-panel/rest/(.*)` location in second location block (`/admin/admin_authentication/check_access`).

Comment: Why not use `$request_uri` in the second block? It should not change between blocks.

Comment: @RichardSmith I change the `$url` to `$request_uri` in the second block but it returns `/admin/admin_authentication/check_access` not `/admin-panel/rest/....`

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi any solution for this question? Thanks.